# How to perform string replace operation using pandas in python?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where the Items columns is a list.

```
cust_id   Items
100     ['item1','item2','item3']
101     ['item5','item8','item9']
102     ['item2','item4']
```

I want to convert the above dataframe to the below format.

```
cust_id  Items
100     item1 item2 item3
101     item5 item8 item9
102     item2 item4
```

I tried using the pandas built in string replace function put its returning the original column without actually performing the string replace operation.

```
df['Items']=(df['Items'].astype(str)).replace({"['":"", "', '":" ", "']":"" },method='string')
```

Please advise

**Update:**

I used the below code to create the original dataframe.

```
df=df1.groupby(['cust_id'])['Items'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: Sorry are the elements lists or a string of a list? Can you post code to construct your df to avoid ambiguity

Comment: Why not just use an `apply` on the column, and do something like `lambda lst: ' '.join(lst)`

Comment: @EdChum I have added the code to reconstruct my original df.

Comment: @Brian This is new info for me, i will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the elements are really `list` , then you can use `str.join()` on the list along with `series.apply` method . Example -

```
In [159]: df = pd.DataFrame([[100,['item1','item2','item3']],[101,['item5','item8','item9']],[102,['item2','item4']]],columns=['cust_id','Items'])

In [160]: df
Out[160]:
   cust_id                  Items
0      100  [item1, item2, item3]
1      101  [item5, item8, item9]
2      102         [item2, item4]

In [161]: df['Items'] = df['Items'].apply(' '.join)

In [162]: df
Out[162]:
   cust_id                Items
0      100    item1 item2 item3
1      101    item5 item8 item9
2      102          item2 item4
```

Comment: You can just use `df['Items'].apply(' '.join)` here`

Comment: what does ' ' mean in the apply function?

Comment: @mrcet007 its the space, which is being used inbetween the different elements.

Comment: Thanks! Can someone also explain why pd.replace doesnt work 7 what is wrong with the code i tried?

Comment: because `series.replace()` is for replacing whole values, what you actually wanted to use was `series.str.replace()` . but there you cannot use `dict`, you would have to provide a regular expression or multiple `.str.replace()` .

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of the syntax to specify regular expression?

Comment: It would be very very complex (if at all possible) to do what you want with regular expression. If you really want to know, you can use check out [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) , which is what `.str.replace()` internallly uses.